# Raphael Click Handler Not Firing

Tags: javascript, click, raphael

(I've previously also tried JQuery, which doesn't seem to work either.)

I have `emitterButton`, which is a circle in Raphael, defined as follows inside a function:

```
  emitterButton = canvas.circle(emitter_center_x,emitter_center_y,BUTTON_RADIUS)
                        .attr({'fill':BUTTON_COLOR_UNPRESSED})
                        .attr({'id':'emitterButton'});
```

. When I try to attach a click handler, via

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log("This is a hi!");
  console.log(emitterButton);
  emitterButton.click(function(){
    console.log("Hi!");
    if(emitterButton.attr('fill')==BUTTON_COLOR_UNPRESSED){
      console.log("Hi, again!");
      emitterButton.attr({'fill':BUTTON_COLOR_PRESSED});
    }
  });
});
```

the first two `console.log` statements fire, but the next two don't. Why isn't my click function working?

Comment: Why say "I've _previously_ also tried JQuery," when you're still using jQuery?

Comment: I previously used $('#emitterButton'), a JQuery ID tag I attached to the emmiterButton, rather than the emitterButton Raphael element itself in the line emitterButton.click(function(){...})

Comment: Oh...OK. Could you make a fiddle or something of the like so we can see more of what's happening?

Comment: http://rawgit.com/ylx/PhET/master/bendingLight/bendingLight.html

Comment: I'm not quite sure you can set a Raphael elements id that way (I think it may vary by version, but not sure). Try emitterButton.node.id='emitterButton' out of interest. I'd also keep an eye on your variable scope within functions, I think there's no specific issue to stop it working there, but you may want to set a var somewhere for emitterButton to be clear on that (I may have missed it though).